# razor page not refreshing model on page DotNet Core 2

Tags: razor, .net-core

OK, 
I make an ajax request to a controller action that updates a sql database, that then refires my index controller.
That fires fine and it hits the index action as expected.

`return RedirectToAction("Index");`

In the index it rebuilds a model based on data in a sql database which I reference on the index.cshtml.
This should then change the view state on the index page based on this.

Below is a small example of what I would like it to do, however nothing happens.

If I do a ctl + F5 then the state updates but I was under the assumption that changing the view model should reload the page if its different.

FYI the states are Bools

```
@if (@Model.State1)
{
   shows one type of button
}

@if (@Model.State2)
{
    shows another type of button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to answer and fix this myself, by calling an asp-action as part of the razor logic it refires the view